# To Display Current Section name as a header in Thesis Writing

Tags: header-footer, thesis

[image: *enter image description here*]

Please guide me, what should i used instead of this code, so that the current section name will be displayed instead of the chapter name as a left side of the header in the page.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Instead of posting a screenshot of code it's better to show some of your code such that users can start immediately

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `\rightmark` instead of `\leftmark` in your `\rhead` declaration. `\rightmark` contains the section info, while `\leftmark` is for the chapter:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%\lhead[\normalfont\thepage]{\fancyplain{}\slshape{\rightmark}}
%\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\slshape{\rightmark}}]{\normalfont\thepage}

\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\normalfont\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\fancyplain{}\slshape{\rightmark}}
\fancyfoot{}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\chapter{C1}

\section{S1}

\newpage
testpage 1
\newpage
testpage 2

\end{document}
```

Note that I used `\fancyhead` instead of `\lhead` and `\rhead`. It does the same, but you don't have to repeat everything.

Comment: Please, remove `\rm` and change it into `\normalfont`. Note that `\rm` has been deprecated for 20 years. Also `\sl` should be `\slshape`.

Comment: @egreg Done. I didn't think too much about the font style, just copied. `\rm` being deprecated is a good reason why I didn't know it :)